# Exponential inequality to Different Bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this exponential equation if I can't make 6 in base 2?
$$ 6 - 2^x \geq 4^x $$
I know that the solution is $ x \in ]-\infty,1]  $ because it just makes sense that $ 6-2=4$
I just don't know how to do it by analytical method.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$
4^x = 2^{2x}
$$  so your inequality reads

$$
2^{2x}+2^x-6\leq 0
$$  or

$$
u^2+u-6\leq 0
$$ where $u=2^x$.  Now factor to find the zeros and check the sign on either side of the zeros.  Essentially you want to make a "sign chart".

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=2^x>0.\,$ Then the inequality becomes

$$\begin{align} 6-y\ge y^2 & \iff y^2+y-6=(y-2)(y+3)\le0 \\ & \iff y=2^x\in(0,2]\\ &\iff x\in(-\infty ,1]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=2^x$. Then, the inequality becomes $$6-u\ge u^2$$which implies that $u^2+u-6\le 0$. This implies that $(u+3)(u-2)\le 0$ which is equivalent to $-3\le u\le 2$. Also, since $u=2^x$, $u>0$. Thus, $0<2^x\le 2$ which gives your desired interval of solutions.